# Include all modules inside a module in ocaml

Tags: module, ocaml

Imagine I have a series of modules `A1..An` `B1..Bn` all of them a complete compilation unit. Now I define a two new modules with those modules as nested:

```
(* A.mli *)
module A : sig
  module A1
  ...
  module An
end
(* A.ml *)
module A1 = A1
..
module An = An

(* B.mli *)
module B : sig
  open A
  module B1
  ...
  module Bn
end
(* B.ml *)
module B1 = B1
..
module Bn = Bn
```

thus the original modules are re exported using module aliases. Note that modules in `B` may refer to types in modules in `A1..An`!

now, I want to create a new module `AB` such that the signature is:

```
module AB : sig
  module A1
  ...
  module An

  module B1
  ...
  module Bn
end
```

However I don't want to listen all individual modules, just to reexport the contents. Using `-open` is not allowed either. The best I can come up with is:

```
module AB : sig
  include module type of struct include A end
  include module type of struct include B end
end
```

However this will fail as we lose the link between let's say, type `A.A1.t` and `A1.t`. Is there a way to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following would work:

```
module AB : sig
  include A
  include B
end
```

(`module type of` makes types abstracts, so you'd need to add `with type ...` constraints, which is messy with nested modules)